# Azure Stack TP2 install: Invocation of step 60.61 failed

Tags: azure, installation, azure-stack

I'm getting the error  on the POC (proof of concept) machine after running the command `.\InstallAzureStackPOC.ps1.`

[image]

It takes a long time, reboot the POC machine and then "autologon" itself. After it keeps on the deployment process and fails at step 60.61.
Solutions I've tried:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e36ca571-b38d-4098-8ed1-39e3f906f6c2/azure-stack-tp2-deployment-error?forum=AzureStack

http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/MVC/Post/Thread/e36ca571-b38d-4098-8ed1-39e3f906f6c2?category=azurestack

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e36ca571-b38d-4098-8ed1-39e3f906f6c2/azure-stack-tp2-deployment-error?forum=AzureStack

Any ideas about how to fix it?

Comment: this is really a wrong question for stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Rerun the deployment using following command "Invoke-EceAction -RolePath Cloud -ActionType Deployment -Verbose -Start 60"